# XPath: Select class name element with a specific attribute name

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xpath

Having the following XML:

```
<exceptions>
    <exception name="LegacyException"        msg="ERREUR DU MODULE SERVEUR">
        <context name="default"    msg="ERREUR DU MODULE SERVEUR (%1$s) : %2$s" />
    </exception>
</exceptions>
```

How do I select exception name and context name via XPath?

Something like this:

```
  String className = "LegacyException";
  String contextName= "default";       
  String query = "//exception[@name='" + className + "' and context[@name='" + contextName+ "']]";
  XPathExpression<Element> xpe = XPathFactory.instance().compile(query, Filters.element());
```

Comment: Are you looking for xpath expressions that evaluate to `LegacyException` and `default`, or is it something else?

Comment: @JackFleeting yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This xpath expression

```
//exceptions/exception/@name
or 
//exception/@name
```

evaluates to

> LegacyException

while this one

```
//exceptions/exception/context/@name 
or 
//context/@name
```

evaluates to

```
default
```